# Can foam jacking restore slope to my front stoop?

Tags: concrete, foundation, drainage, joists, crawlspace

The stoop in the front door inclines towards the house and guides the water into the crawlspace. The stoop itself is outside the foundation wall of the house and is not fixed to it. The lower part of the rim joist is also behind the stoop under the front door. The photo was taken before the lifting. The owner re-did the siding and the trim under the front door to make them touch the stoop to hide the settlement problem.

I wonder if polyjacking the stoop can make its top a slope away from the house, thus to guide the water away. Some concrete jacking contractor made the stoop top level (slight slope toward the house technically) and refused to lift it more. They said the polyjacking was not typically used for water drainage problem. Is it correct? If yes, why? I know polyjacking is waterproof, and should be okay to use here.

Isn’t polyjacking capable of making a slope? I did consult multiple large concrete companies before the project started, and did mention that I needed a slope. All of them suggested polyjacking. Adding an overhang was considered before the project started, and was passed as it would cost significantly more.

There is some background information I’d like to add. The contractor damaged my front door when they jacked the stoop for the first time, but that damage was caused by a misuse of a prybar, not the polyjacking itself. After I complained, they agreed to replace the door for me. However, they seemed very conservative since then, and refused to lift the concrete more, or told me there were many risks to lift more, e.g., damages to the foundation or wood structure of the house, and/or crack in the stoop, and asked me for all kinds of waiver to release their liabilities.

[image]

Comment: I do not know much about about polyjacking, but it seems to work better for a solid concrete slab on the ground(and might be a temporary fix, unknown).  How those steps were made is an unknown.  Some people on here might know of better fixes to add a proper slope to the top.  There seems to be a few inches from the door to work with.

Comment: @SolarMike That was considered before the project started, and was passed as it costs significantly more. Is polyjacking able to reach my goal?

Comment: That detail was left out of the question.

Comment: @crip659 It's unnecessary to lift the stoop to be flush with the door sill to make a sufficient slope. In fact, only less than one inch lift is needed.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm sorry, but what detail?

Comment: I just mention like you had a few inches to work with, not that it needed all of them.  Slope only needs to be about a 1/4 inch.  I do not enough of what to add and how thick it needs to be to last.

Comment: The detail that you had considered an overhang... Surely it was clear what we were talking about?

Comment: @crip659 Got you, thannk you.

Comment: @SolarMike I see. As the title of the post is about polyjacking, I was trying to keep it focused on that. I can add that anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the roof option is irrelevant. So is the contractor legal situation that was there.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your steps it's difficult to say. What do you know about the overall design and the concrete thickness?

Comment: @isherwood I added the background information so other people can tell if it's physically/technically impossible to lift or it's because the contractor doesn't want to deal with me anymore as they need to buy me a new door. Without the information, I'm restricting the way of thinking to only the enginerring part. If you agree, would you consider to add the background back?

Comment: @isherwood The concrete seems not very thick, as it took few seconds to drill an injection hole. The stoop is not solid, and it's dirt under the concrete top. Behind the stoop is the concrete brick fundation wall and lower part of the rim joist.

Comment: @isherwood I notice that you kindly changed my title as well, from slope to level. Do you think it's unnecessary to make a slope or do you think it's impossible with foam jacking? May I know why? Thank you.

Comment: It was a hasty word choice. Your title was almost nonsensical and not a question. Feel free to revise further. Slope is certainly warranted.